# Laptop doesn't boot (damaged BIOS)?

Tags: boot, laptop, bios

I was suffering from a network issue with my laptop (Acer Aspire 5750), so I went to acer.com and downloaded the latest BIOS update, but when it was installing, it showed an error message saying "IHSI: flash complete error in SMI" then it hanged and didn't respond for a long time. I had to turn the power off, but when I powered it on again, it wouldn't show anything on the screen (black screen) and the BIOS doesn't load. Did I damage the BIOS that way? Is there any fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a reflash of the BIOS.

First format an USB stick with FAT.

Download the latest known working BIOS, and put both FLASHIT.EXE and the BIOS file in the root directory of the stick. Rename the BIOS file to ZG5IA32.FD. This file can be found inside the BIOS exe installer by using 7zip or winrar to extract it. It will be a file with a FD extension.

Turn the laptop off and plug in the USB drive, make sure both battery and AC adapter are connected. Press Fn+Esc, keep it pressed and press the power button to turn the laptop on. Release Fn+Esc after a few seconds, the power button will be blinking. Press the power button once. The laptop will now initiate the BIOS flash, do not interrupt it under any circumstances. After a while the power button will stop blinking, and the laptop will reboot shortly after.

Source: 
http://www.justanswer.com/computer/7gqox-ok-somehow-bricked-bios-aspire-5750g.html.

If that doesn't work you will likely need a new motherboard.

Comment: I think this answer would be better if it stated with some kind of summary or title. For example: "One thing that might help is to revert the BIOS to the last know working version. This can be done with the FLASHIT.EXE program."

Comment: He says the bios file should be a .fd file but when I downloaded the update it was only two files one with a .rom and one with a .bin would those work too, and whick one should I use??

Comment: Please answer me as fast as you can..

Comment: Sorry. I'm at work right now. If you use 7zip or another program like it, the exe is actually a self-extracting archive. If you extract it, there should be an FD file in it.